# Recurrence relations and the Master Theorem

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Although it might be a bit of newbie question, my question is, How can I apply the Master theorem to the following relation:

```
T(n) = 99T(n/100) + log(n!)
```

I'm trying to learn about algorithms, but I'm not really comfortable with logarithms(haven't studied in school yet), so I'd really appreciate a bit of help.
Thanks.

Comment: Try using $\log (n!) = \Theta(n \log n)$.

Comment: Thanks very much, but could please link to a proof of this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation. You asked something similar a few days before also. :)

Comment: yes, I'm really new to this stuff. Thanks very much :)

Comment: You can answer your own question if you have solved it. Just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: ok I will do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $n! \le n^n$, therefore $\log n! \le n \log n$. Then
$$
T(n) \le 99T( \frac{n}{100} ) + n \log n
$$

Let $c=\log_{100} 99 < 1$ and notice that $n \log n$ is polynomially larger than $n^c$. Indeed:
$n \log n \in \Omega(n) \subset \Omega(n^c).$ By the master theorem we have $T(n) = O(n \log n)$.

This is tight because $\Omega(n \log n)$ is also a lower bound since:
$$
T(n) \ge \log n! \ge \log ( \lfloor n/2 \rfloor^{(n/2)} ) 
=  (n/2) \log ( \lfloor n/2 \rfloor)  = \Omega(n \log n).
$$

To summarize, you have $T(n) = \Theta(n \log n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to answer it myself but my answer was wrong so I deleted it. Thank you.